# Execute String as a Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, dynamic

Is there a way I can execute a String as a Linq?
I had a dynamci query and for that I had to convert the Linq expression into string, then append string bulider which has some conditional query.
So whole expression is now in string.
How to execute this string now?
Should I again convert this string to Linq?
How to proceed?

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 if (InstId != String.Empty)
 {
     sb.Append("application.Id ==" + InstId);
 }
 if (BId != String.Empty)
 {
     sb.Append("&& application.BId ==" + BId);
 }
 if (CId != String.Empty)
 {
     sb.Append("&& application.CId ==" + CId);
 }

String query=("from tables in context.Application .........
........join .........."+sb);

var q1=query;
```

Now how to execute this q1?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you *want* to build it up as a string? It would be more efficient and safer (IMO) to do this without using a string representation.

Comment: Well, I mentioned as I had to append some criteria in where clause, so I had to use string builder.

Comment: You can build up LINQ queries without using strings. Everything you've shown in terms of requirements can *definitely* be done without using a string representation.

Comment: I have different criteria for selection if Id are empty (as I send them as string), so every time my query will change. And this is just a sample, I will have to execute it.

Comment: Again, *none* of this prevents you from building up the query dynamically without using strings. Marcin's answer is the way forward. Introducing string conversions will only lead to pain in the long run, I'm sure.

Comment: Thank you so much and I learnt that being flexible in our approach works well (listening to others advise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `StringBuilder` for that:

```
var query = context.Application;

if (InstId != String.Empty)
{
    query = query.Where(a => a.Id == InstId);
}
if (BId != String.Empty)
{
    query = query.Where(a => a.BId == BId);
}
if (CId != String.Empty)
{
    query = query.Where(a => a.CId == CId);
}

var items = query.Join(/* your join here */).ToList();
```

Query won't be executed untill `ToList` or other methods like that is invoked, so you can append `Where()` as long you'd like to.

Comment: I have number of joins in my query and then I use the criteria in the where clause from different tables which are joined.

Comment: So prepare `queryA`, `queryB`, etc. in similar way and join them. Then you can add another `Where` on joined data as well.

Comment: :Thank you so much I did the same way and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't necessarily think it's a  great practice in a lot of cases, there is a [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) library that allows you to do just that.

In general, if possible, I'd recommend using something that can be more strongly type checked, such as [@MarcinJuraszak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15902498/940)'s response or something like a [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) class.

Comment: I had already gone through the above mentioned link and that was of no help as I am having number of joins in my query.

Comment: @ItiTyagi what specific issues do the joins cause? Building up a `Where` clause predicate will work on single tables or joined tables

Comment: I am able to solve that by the above mentioned way and it is working fine now.